Finding shortest road distance between points on two datasets QGIS
I have two point datasets:

Communities and
Vet clinics

I am trying to find the nearest distance between each community and the closest vet clinic, but would ideally like to link this to a roads shapefile rather than the “as the crow flies” distance from the normal distance matrix.
Does anyone know if this is possible and if so how?
